# Angular2: Inject external Component into other component via directive not working

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I want child component template to load into parent component template. (for the lack of better wording I call them child and parent)

This is my child:

```
import {Component,Directive, ElementRef, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {IONIC_DIRECTIVES} from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({ 
  selector: '[parentselector]',
  template: '<div>I AM A CHILD</div>',
  directives: [IONIC_DIRECTIVES] 
})


export class ChildPage {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

This is my parent:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/parent/parent.html',
    directives: [ChildPage]
})
```

And the HTML of Parent:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slides>
        <ion-slide><parentselector>Parent To Be Overriden</parentselector>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Angular 2 Cheat Sheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html) (search for selector) it says that by using brackets you are limiting where your directive can be called. For example:

```
selector:'[parentselector]' - means you can only select as an attribute
selector:'parentselector' - means you can only select as an element
selector:'.parentselector' - means you can only select as a css class
```

So if you take off the `[]` all should be well